# Login with your Google accout with OAuth2.0 [Blogger API]

Tags: java, android, oauth, accountmanager

We are developing an app for Android that you can login with your Google account and read, write, delete posts from Blogger. We have looked up many OAuth2.0 examples but none works and many of them are to old. Blogger API dont have this function?

**We want people to write there google email/password in 2 different EditText and login.**
Or, if it goes to the google account on the phone and log you in without any password (doesnt matter)

We tried accountManager and other examples but none works.
We have the Blogger API, client Id, but not the client secret. Its not there.

Someone who got a WORKABLE example or finished java file with the text, so we can put in our API key, client Id and so on? Thanks.

(And yes, we read many examples, tried many many pages and tutorials from StackOverflow and youtube. None works, to old.)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As of September 2015, There is no way to preauthorize someone for Blogger so I believe the only way to access Blogger Api is to generate access token through Auth 2 Playground ( https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ ) and then using the token for API call.

Credentials authentication might have been working earlier but has now been discontinued.